# Receving an error while taking the backup using "pg_basebackup" utility

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

We are using below command to take the backup of the database.

```
$PGHOME/bin/pg_basebackup -p 5433 -U postgres -P -v -x --format=tar --gzip --compress=1 --pgdata=- -D /opt/rao
```

​While taking the backup we have received below error.​

> ```
> ​transaction log start point: 285/8F000080
> pg_basebackup: could not get transaction log end position from server: FATAL:  requested WAL segment 00000001000002850000008F has already been removed​
> ```

Please guide me why and how to handle this error. Do you want me to change any of the option in my `pg_basebackup` command let me know.

Please clarify me what it means `--pgdata=--D` in my above  pg_basebackup command.

Answer (score 2):

```
-D directory
--pgdata=directory
```

This specifies the directory to write the output to.
When the backup is in tar mode, and the directory is specified as - (dash), the tar file will be written to stdout. This parameter is required.

```
FATAL:  requested WAL segment 00000001000002850000008F has already been removed
```

means that the master hasn't kept enough history to bring the standby back up to date.

You can use [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgbasebackup.html) to create a new slave:

```
pg_basebackup -h masterhost -U postgres -D path --progress --verbose -c fast
```

When having a WAL archive, you can try restore_command. The pg_basebackup creates an entirely new slave in an empty directory.

Comment: We are using below command to take the backup of the database. ` $PGHOME/bin/pg_basebackup -p 5433 -U postgres -P -v -x --format=tar --gzip --compress=1 --pgdata=- -D /opt/rao  `                                             We are using both -D directory &  --pgdata=directory  . Could I remove any one out of -D or --pgdata. Becuase both are related to specify the directory. Am I correct?

Comment: `-D /opt/rao` and `--pgdata=/opt/rao` are equivalent, one is the short form.. ;)
Please accept the answer in case it was what you were looking for..